# How to determine which template will be used

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning about templates in c++ and I found the following example.

From what I understand, the compiler should always try to use the most "specialized" template if there is no non-template functions matching, yet in this example, the first call result in calling function a(T*) instead of a(int*). Why? And why does second call act differently?

```
template<typename T>
void a(T) {cout << "(T)" << endl;}

template<>
void a<>(int*) {cout << "(int)" << endl;}

template<typename T>
void a(T*) {cout << "(T*)" << endl;}

template<typename T>
void b(T) {cout << "(T)" << endl;}

template<typename T>
void b(T*) {cout << "(T*)" << endl;}

template<>
void b<>(int*) {cout << "(int)" << endl;}

int main()
{
  int i;
  a(&i);
  b(&i); 
  return 0;
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
(T*)
(int)
```

I expected it to be:

```
(int)
(int)
```

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only primary templates (so no specializations) are taken into account to select more specialized overloads.

Once selection is done with primary template, we use the specialization if any.

Now, `template<> void a<>(int*);` can only be specialization of `template<typename T> void a(T)` (the other version has not been seen).

and `template<> void b<>(int*);` is specialization of `template<typename T> void b(T*)` (it is the more specialized matching overloads).

Notice that you might select specialization of `b` by providing template instead of letting compiler deduce:

- `template<> void b<>(int*)`     -> `template<typename T> void b(T*) with T=int`
- `template<> void b<int>(int*)`  -> `template<typename T> void b(T*) with T=int`
- `template<> void b<int*>(int*)` -> `template<typename T> void b(T)  with T=int*`

so for:

```
int i;
a(&i); // a<T*> with T=int*, no specialization for a<U*> (U=int) exist -> generic template called
b(&i); // b<T*> with T=int*, specialization for b<U*> (U=int) exists -> specialization called
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the difference of the declaration order, the specialization belongs to different primary template.

For the 1st case, the specialization belongs to `a(T)`. For the 2nd case, the specialization belongs to `b(T*)`. During overload resolution between primary templates, the version taking `T*` is always selected; then in the 1st case, the specialization won't be considered because it's not the specialization of `a(T*`). But it's selected in the 2nd case because `b(T*)` has the specialization.

i.e.

For the 1st case

overloading

- a(T)

  - specialization --> a(int*)
- a(T*) // selected in overload resolution

For the 2nd case

overloading

- b(T)
- b(T*) // selected in overload resolution

  - specialization --> b(int*) // then the specialization is selected